# Python: List comprehension significantly faster than Filter?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I've been time-testing my code for Project Euler written in Python, trying to do Functional programming. The results for the following two lines of code vary wildly although I can't think of a reason for such a huge improvement in the second line...

```
method1 is run by timeit.Timer.timeit() in 216.869596283 seconds
method2 is run by timeit.Timer.timeit() in 162.596869065 seconds
```

Anybody able to enlighten me?

```
def method1():
  reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, filter(lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, xrange(1000)))

def method2():
  reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [x for x in xrange(1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0])
```

EDIT: I know that filter is inherently slower than list comprehension... I'm just not understanding WHY?

Comment: Function calls are expensive compared to language constructs